# Parse the dictionary values in CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-2.7, group-by

CSV File contains

```
id,type,attributes
1,xx,{'data': { 'attributes': {'aggregations': [{'space': 'sum','time': 'sum'}],'created_at': '2020-03-25T09:48:37.463835Z','include_percentiles': true,'metric_type': 'count','modified_at': '2020-03-25T09:48:37.463835Z','tags': ['app','datacenter']},'id': 'test.metric.latency','type': 'manage_tags'}}
```

how to parse the attributes from CSV file using pandas dataframe.

Expecting output

```
id type space created_at                  include_percentiles metric_type tags 
1  xx   sum   020-03-25T09:48:37.463835Z  true                count       app   
1  xx   sum   020-03-25T09:48:37.463835Z  true                count       datacenter
```

Comment: You seem to have something similar to a string representation of a Python dictionary as the attributes value. I have no idea how you'd manage that with pandas. You'll struggle even with plain file handling as the data do not represent an actual Python dictionary that could otherwise be managed with ast.literal_eval(). It's not JSON either. Not sure what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge here is that the CSV data are not in a format that can be handled by a traditional parser.

This is because the data are essentially comma-delimited **but** the 'attributes' value contains commas that are not value separators.

The 'attributes' value is neither a string representation of a Python dictionary nor is it JSON.

If the data are meant to represent a Python dictionary then the only issue (with the data as shown) is the value 'true'. We can overcome that by changing it to True. Let's also assume that there might be a value of 'false' so we'll deal with that too.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from ast import literal_eval


alldata = []

with open('/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.csv') as data:
    next(data)  # skip column names
    for line in data:
        _id, _type, *dr = line.split(',')
        ds = ','.join(dr).replace('true', 'True').replace('false', 'False')
        attrs = literal_eval(ds)['data']['attributes']
        rd = {
            'id': _id,
            'type': _type,
            'space': attrs['aggregations'][0]['space'],
            'created_at': attrs['created_at'],
            'include_percentiles': attrs['include_percentiles'],
            'metric_type': attrs['metric_type']
        }
        for tag in attrs['tags']:
            rd['tags'] = tag
            alldata.append(rd)

print(DataFrame(alldata))
```

**Output:**

```
  id type space                   created_at  include_percentiles metric_type        tags
0  1   xx   sum  2020-03-25T09:48:37.463835Z                 True       count         app
1  1   xx   sum  2020-03-25T09:48:37.463835Z                 True       count  datacenter
```